# How to use ember-cli-clock to reload the route's model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using [ember-cli-clock](https://github.com/jerel/ember-cli-clock) which lets me do this in a controller:

```
  date: function () {
    return moment().format('dddd MMMM Do');
  }.property('clock.minute'),
```

This is really neat and as you can guess, live updates dates and times on a particular time interval.

How do I use this in order to reload the model for a route when the date changes (or anything else for that matter)?

The model does have a [reload](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/278a0b863f0b1b2494fe2319ac12be6167195f6b) method, I'm just not sure how to hook into it from the clock event?

Comment: You could send an action and catch it on the route.

Comment: @Kitler how/from where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [observer](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_observer) in your controller:

```
date: function() {
    return moment().format('dddd MMMM Do');
}.property('clock.minute'),

refreshModel: function() {
    // You can also do some logic here to conditionally
    // reload the model when the clock is in a certain state
    this.get('model').reload();
}.observes('clock.minute')
```